# Laravel 5.8 assets url does not working the same in localhost and server

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

I am trying to get an image from public/assets/img folder, the image is exist into an img folder which is into assets folder which is into the public folder. I used `src="{{ asset('/assets/img/example.png') }}"` to get the image and it works correctly in my localhost, but when I push the code to the server (the server is UNIX) the code did not work, but when I changed it to be like `src="{{ asset('../public/assets/img/example.png') }}"` it worked into the server but it wasn't in local.

So, do we have a one way to get the image from both without using different urls into asset() for local and server. Or why in the server I must add "../public" before "/assets/img/example.png" even its not in local?

Comment: did you run this command in your server
php artisan storage:link

Comment: what does asset() generate on the production server?

Comment: No, I did not run php artisan atorage:link into both server and local. Regarding to what asset() generate in the server the url like the following: https://example.com/../public/assets/img/example.png and when used without '../public' it genrates  https://example.com/assets/img/example.png

Answer (score 1):

First of all, using `../public` on the server is not right.

I suspect it is because you used `"/assets/img/example.png"` instead of `"assets/img/example.png"`

Either way, if the issue persists, **you can override your public path on the server** to avoid updating every code you use the `{{ asset() }}` function.

Add this app bind code to the AppServiceProvider.php in your Laravel Project located in

`<laravel-project-name>/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

```php
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
            return realpath(base_path().'../public');
        });
    }
```

This way, you won't have to change every code you use the `{{ asset() }}` function on the server.

Comment: I tried to add the code into register() method in server as u said but the code does not work for me. I found that the issue because the public folder in the larval project located in the public _html in the server but the rest of file located outside the public html! because of that I should add ../public in the server. But what is the perfect solution? and how I can fix it.

Comment: By default, the `{{ assets() }}` function should point to your public folder. and to fix this issue the best solution is to override it like I said. if `return realpath(base_path().'../pubic');` does not work, Try using `return __DIR__;` instead.

Comment: it seems that the AppServiceProvider did not called, since any changes that I made did not applied. you know why?

Comment: I just installed Laravel v5.8 on my system and uploaded it to the server without any issues with the {{ asset() }} function. Do you have a GIT REPO for your project? Because, I am finding it hard to replicate your problem.

Comment: Yes I have GIT Repo for my project. If you want I can show you my problem directly by teamviewer since i am stuck and I have to go live as soon as possible with my project.

Comment: Please note that I am using cPanel on my server and the progress to upload Laravel prroject to cPanel is to put the parent folder which contains the all folders and files except public folder in cPanel (outside public_html) and the public folder into public html

Comment: No problem with Teamviewer. send me a mail whenever you are ready. oyenirantunji2339@gmail.com